# Iterating through struct values from embedded struct

Tags: go, struct

I have the following struct

```
type ChartOpts struct {
    Name              mypackage.Sometype
    Repo              mypackage.Anothertype
    mypackage.SomeSpecialStructType
}
```

Then I create the following receiver for `mypackage.SomeSpecialStructType` as follows:

```
func (c SomeSpecialStructType) BindFlags() {
    fields := reflect.TypeOf(c)
    values := reflect.ValueOf(c)
    num := fields.NumField()
    for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
        switch v := values.Field(i).Interface().(type) {
        case OrmosFlag:
            fmt.Printf("%#T\n", v)
            //v.BindPersistentFlag(cobCom)
            log.Println("HERE")
        default:
            log.Println("ERROR")
        }
    }

}
```

As (perhaps) becomes evident from the code, I want to leverage embedding so that the embedded type (that I was expecting to have access to the outer struct fields) can perform some operations on them.

The code does not works given that `num` is 0 here (makes since given that `SomeSpecialStructType` has zero fields, just a receiver)

I know I can just copy-paste the specific receiver on each and every ChartOpts struct I create (there will be plenty of them coming) but just trying to be DRY here.

Comment: "so that the embedded type (that I was expecting to have access to the outer struct fields)" your expectations are 100% wrong. An embedded struct does know know nothing  about where, how or  even _that_ it  is embedded.

Comment: such an expectation was based on type promotion, where the `BindFlags()` would be called from the outer struct (and NOT from the embedded one) so that the reflection would allow the method to gain access to the (outer) struct fields; this was actually my assumption

Comment: @pkaramol the embedded struct simply does not have the information about where it is relative to the outer struct.

Comment: There is no "type promotion" and BindFlags is not  called from the outer struct. Embedding is just  _syntactic_ sugar. It lets your omit field name. That's all. No magic, just _one_ type name and one . less to  type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedding is not inheritance. When you embed a struct type into another, you are essentially composing a new type, not extending the embedded type.

```
type Inner struct {
  X int
}

type Outer struct {
  Inner
}
```

Above, `Outer` is a struct containing `Inner`. When you declare a variable of type `Outer`, you can access the fields of the `Inner` struct by:

```
x:=Outer{}
x.Inner.X=1
x.X=1
```

So in fact this is no different from:

```
type Outer struct {
   Inner Inner
}
```

with the difference that the field name is omitted. So you can shortcut the field name when you access the variables.

in short: there is no way a method of an inner struct can access the embedding struct. If you need that, have a constructor method for the outer struct that sets a pointer in the inner struct. Also, pass around a pointer to the returned struct. If you copy the struct, the pointer needs to be adjusted.

```
type Outer struct {
   Inner
}
type Inner struct {
   X int
   o *Outer
}

func NewOuter() *Outer {
   ret:=&Outer{}
   ret.outer=ret
   return ret
}
```